# How to make Close button work as Minimize: C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I make the (default) **Close** button (at top right corner) in my application, to work it as **Minimize**.
Actually I want to minimize the application on clicking the cross-symbol, but exit the application, when use clicks on my menu option **Exit**.

I wrote this code for minimizing the form on clicking close button:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (minimize_on_close == "Yes")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
```

and wrote this code for exiting the application, on clicking exit from menu options.

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

But now, when I click on **Exit** menu option, then also the form is being minimized, and not exiting.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please, oh, please don't use string literals like this - *minimize_on_close == "Yes"*

Comment: then what should I use?

Comment: Please don't minimize on the "close" button. I want to kill any application using it (and I want to know what it does when I click it). Whether its a "always on tray app" shouldn't matter. I don't want to go searching for the quit/exit option. Don't show a close button if it doesn't do what I expect.

Comment: @user1547766: In this case, a *bool* should be good enough. For more options, use an *enum* or even constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see whether [`FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) is equal to `CloseReason.UserClosing` before deciding to minimize the window. Alternatively, compare for `CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall`.

From the documentation for [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx):

> ## Members
>
> ...
>
> ### UserClosing
>
> The user is closing the form through the user interface (UI), for example by clicking the Close button on the form window, selecting Close from the window's control menu, or pressing ALT+F4.
>
> ...
>
> ### ApplicationExitCall
>
> The Exit method of the Application class was invoked.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**EDIT**
May use `Resize` Event to do it,

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  { 
  if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) 
  this.Hide(); 
  }
```

Then using the `FormClosing` Event to cancel Close and minimize the Form as below

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{ 
if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) 
 { 
  e.Cancel = true; 
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to minimize a form in the `Dispose` method.

Comment: Just to check the `Forms.WindowState`